# display all posts in current category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, loop

I am trying to display all the content/posts assigned to a certain category.

I have a custom post type set up called 'Videos' and within this I have created categories called music, commercial, promo & short film.

Now everytime I post under the videos post type and assign it to a category I want to display all the content assigned to that category.

My attempt so far:

```
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    //$args = array( 'post_type' => 'videos', 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC' );
    $ytubeID = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_youtubeID', true);
    $vimID = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_vimeoID', true);

    if ($ytubeID || $vimID){
        if ($ytubeID && in_array($videos_cat_to_check,$videos_categories)){ // CHECK IF CURRENT POST HAS CATEGORY MUSIC 

            echo '<div class="video">';

            echo '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ytubeID.'"  allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" width="640" height="390">';

            echo '</iframe>';

            } elseif ($vimID){
            echo '<br />';
            echo '<div class="video">';
            echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$vimID.'" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
            }//end if yutbeID or vimIDthe_excerpt(); //excerpt added for information
            echo '</div>';
    }


    echo the_content();

    $taxonomy = 'category';

    // get the term IDs assigned to post.
    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    // separator between links
    $separator = ', ';

    if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

        $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
        $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
        $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

        // display post categories
        echo  $terms;
    }

endwhile;


?>
```

I am displaying a vimeo/youtube video with a title and description. The user enters the video ID into a custom meta box which then displays the video. I want to display all the videos/posts for the current category. Each category has different videos assigned to them.

Comment: In what **context** do you want to display all posts? In the category archive index, or in the single CPT post?

Comment: I would like to display all posts on the single-custom-post-type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$query = WP_Query('post_type=videos');
while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
      <?php the_title();?>
       <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
```

You need to tell WP_Query what post type we need to call here `post_type=post-type-slug`

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment:

> I would like to display all posts on the single-custom-post-type

You're saying that, in the single CPT post view, you want to display *both* the single CPT post, *and also* a list of all CPT posts in the same category.

To do that:

1. Create `single-{post-type}.php`
2. The queried single CPT post is output via the default loop:

   ```
   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       // Loop markup here
   endwhile; endif
   ```
3. You will then need to retrieve the appropriate category:

   ```
   $cpt_cats = get_the_category();
   $cpt_cat = $cpt_cats[0]->term_id;
   ```
4. You will then need to add a *secondary query* to query all CPT posts in the given category

   ```
   $cpt_query = new WP_Query( array( 
       'post_type' => $cpt_slug, 'cat' => $cpt_cat, 'posts_per_page' => -1
   ) );
   ```
5. You will then need to create a custom loop to output your custom query:

   ```
   if ( $cpt_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $cpt_query->have_posts() ) : $cpt_query->the_post();
       // Secondary loop markup here
   endwhile; endif;
   // Don't forget this
   wp_reset_postdata();
   ```

(You will need to change the custom query parameters to suit your needs, and fill in the HTML markup where appropriate.)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but could you show me how this would fit into my code? I'm not sure where I need to add the code you suggested. Many thanks.

Comment: The code goes in the `single-{post-type}.php` file.